# How to recalculate after deleting part of the form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering how is it possible to re-calculate when a part of the form gets deleted. My code as of now sums up all prices using JavaScript correctly however when a part of the form gets deleted, the price does not update accordingly.

I thought of using an array but unable to understand how can I tell it to "delete" a certain value when the specfic form part is deleted.

Part of my code can be checked in https://jsfiddle.net/drd1jnLf/

**EDIT (9th September 2017)**

One way to do it is add all values in an array and onclick, get index of class and deduct total from array[index]. Was able to make it work but whenever I update the price, I delete the class to not have the price repopulate however then it all stops working all together. My main issue lies in the code `$(this).next().removeClass().end();` which can bee seen below:

```
    $('.cross').click(function(){
    var index = $(".cross").index(this);
    totalPrice = totalPrice - priceArray[index];
    priceArray.splice(index,1);
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = "Total Price: OMR " + totalPrice;
    $(this).next().removeClass().end();
});
```

Comment: were that delete operation you perform in this code....?

Comment: You are not calling providePrice to recalculate the price, seems.

Comment: @MaulikBhatt as I am using an image, it shows as a blank circle in my code.

Comment: @4esn0k I tried that, it does not recalculate even after deleting the form. I shall edit my code to show the same.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the id that you create insted of removing the form you click on 
Its simple there is an array to which you are adding and will be posting so try to remove entries with id and like you are creating with id so it will remove all the entries related to it.

Comment: When removing the additional form, I am deleting everything, even the additional ID. Also, my deletion has to be the full additional form and not part of it.

Comment: looking at your function I can say that you are removing id but not removing the amount you added

Comment: I know that. I am looking for a way for that to happen hence my question in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code and was able to make my code work based on my above speculations.

```
//after deletion, update total price and remove deleted form details
  $('.cross').click(function() {
    var index = $(".cross").index(this);
    totalPrice = totalPrice - priceArray[index];
    priceArray.splice(index, 1);
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = "Total Price: OMR " + totalPrice;
    $(this).next().removeClass().addClass('changed').slideUp(500, function() {
      $(this).html('').end();
      providePrice();
    });
  });
```

I had to create another function to remove all the available data to not cause duplication and errors which can be seen here `$(this).next().removeClass().addClass('changed').slideUp(500, function() {$(this).html('').end(); providePrice();});`

Reason why I am recalling `providePrice()` function is to update the price in case it doesn't.

[JSFiddle Answer](https://jsfiddle.net/drd1jnLf/1/)